# No cabal file found but there is one

Tags: haskell, sandbox, cabal

I am trying to install a project in a sandbox for which I have different branches.
When I checkout one branch and go cabal install, it works like a breeze.
However, when I checkout the other branch, I get:

```
cabal: No cabal file found.
Please create a package description file <pkgname>.cabal
```

But there IS a cabal file! I don't understand.

EDIT:  after doing cabal install -v3

```
Using a sandbox located at
~/projets/alternative/m_p/MP/.cabal-sandbox
Searching for ghc in path.
Found ghc at /usr/bin/ghc
("/usr/bin/ghc",["--numeric-version"])
/usr/bin/ghc is version 7.4.1
looking for tool ghc-pkg near compiler in /usr/bin
found ghc-pkg in /usr/bin/ghc-pkg
("/usr/bin/ghc-pkg",["--version"])
/usr/bin/ghc-pkg is version 7.4.1
("/usr/bin/ghc",["--supported-languages"])
("/usr/bin/ghc",["--info"])
The package database already exists:
~/projets/alternative/m_p/MP/.cabal-sandbox/i386-linux-ghc-7.4.1-packages.conf.d
Reading available packages...
cabal: No cabal file found.
Please create a package description file <pkgname>.cabal
```

Comment: Try `cabal install -v3` to get more debugging output. There's not much to go on in your question.

Comment: edited with the output.

Comment: What does `ls *.cabal` say?

Comment: ls *.cabal says MP.cabal

Comment: Can you diff the two cabal files from the different branches?

Comment: There are only differences in dependencies and used libs, because the two branches work on different aspects of the projets. The rest is identical.

Comment: Try to clean sandbox, recreate it again and then `cabal install`. According to [source code of Cabal](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/blob/7732306ab10023edf8036306a8ce71e20b894837/Cabal/Distribution/Simple/Utils.hs#L1069) that can be only if Cabal is searching in wrong directory

Comment: This happened to me recently. In one branch I had done `cabal sandbox add-source libs/…` within my local repository When I switched to the other branch, the *library's* `.cabal` file went away, and I think that triggered the problem.

Comment: I have similar problem with travis and external stack packages and no solution